# How to snap an object to another without moving origin?

Tags: snapping

Say I have two cubes. I want to move one entire cube so that one of it's vertices snaps to a vertex of the other cube, WITHOUT having to faff around moving the origin of one of the cubes. Is this possible?

Similarly, can I do this with the midpoint of one of the cubes' sides instead of a vertex? i.e. snapping a midpoint to a vertex or another midpoint?

EDIT: thought I should mention that I'm on Blender 2.8

Answer (score 1):

Select the cube you want to move, go into Edit mode, turn on snapping to vertex, select all vertices and choose one as the active by clicking on it, change pivot point to active element. You can now snap the whole cube from this vertex to one from the other cube.

To snap the center of the cube to the other cube, change pivot point back to median pooint. Also snapping target to Center instead of Closest. Play around with it, you can do it all just by changing pivot point and target options.

Comment: I did say 'without moving the origin of one of the cubes', which seems to be what you're suggesting I do. Can't this be done quickly, like in Sketchup where you can just literally pick an object up by one of it's vertexes without faffing around in edit mode?

Also you'll notice I said the midpoint *of an edge*, not the centre of the cube.

Comment: Ok this can be done but in a couple of clics, click your cube in Object mode, pivot point median and snap to vertex. Hit G to move it, then you have to hover on one of the vertex you want to snap onto, hit A to add a snap point, hover the other vertex of the edge, hit A, now your cube should be exactly between the 2 vertex, therefore in the middle of your edge... But yeh, blender is not a CAD software so it's a bit more clics.

Comment: That kinda works for the midpoint thing. Still can't get a vertex to snap to a vertex though. It was useful to discover the <kbd>A</kbd> key though, that's half of the battle.

Comment: You need to have snapping set to vertex and closest, then the vertex that will snap depends on where you mouse was hovering before you start moving the cube with G. So you hover the vertex that you want to be snapping, hit G, then hover on the vertex you want to snap on. This is all very dependant on mouse placement, it's very fast and powerful once you get how it works.